# Why `return` doesn't interrupt the function?

Tags: javascript

When I call in console `foo()`, it returns `4`.

```
function foo()
{
    function bar(){
        return 3;
    };

    return bar();

    function bar(){
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Does it mean that `return` only interrupts during execution not during declaration? Your explanations are invaluable.

Comment: functions are hoisted.

Comment: ^ function *declarations* are hoisted.

Comment: [Function declaration hosting on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)

Comment: Thank you  Daniel for the notion, Felix for the detail, and MDN for the examples in the good link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns 4 because function declarations are parsed and assigned before everything else. It is not like `var f = function () { ... };`.

Comment: Yes this is it, function declaration hoisting. thank you waiting for timer to expire